# boolean algebra simplification solving

Tags: boolean-algebra

Can anyone help me out on this boolean algebra simplification...im not sure with my answer.

X’YZ + XY’Z’ + X’Y’Z’ + XY’Z + XYZ my answer is x'yz+y'z'+xz but badly not sure of it! can you check thnks in advance

I am assuming the "()" with "'" means the over-score above the variables

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
XY'Z' + X'Y'Z' &=  (X+X')Y'Z' \qquad &\mbox{distributivity}\\ &= Y'Z' \qquad &\mbox{ since } X' + X = 1\\
XY'Z + XYZ &= Y'XZ + YXZ \qquad &\mbox{commutativity}\\&= (Y'+Y)XZ \qquad &\mbox{distributivity}\\&= XZ \qquad &\mbox{ since }Y' + Y = 1\end{align}

So your answer is correct.